# One Ticket, Two Locations & Two Luggage Delivery Location

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines, south-africa, nairobi

I am travelling to South Africa  transiting via Nairobi before returning to Nairobi after a week, Can the airline hold/keep my luggage for me in Nairobi till I return to Nairobi

Comment: What's your air company?

Answer (score 5):

No. The airline will not hold luggage for you. Not voluntarily anyway. If you failed to pick up your luggage at the airport, they would probably hold if for a few days providing it didn't go missing. It's not a recommended strategy though.

Ideally you should look for a left luggage service at the airport or in the city. If you're staying at a hotel in Nairobi, it is often possible to leave luggage with them for little or no payment.